# My CSS is not working correctly when "sails lift --prod" as it does when "sails lift"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, deployment, sails.js, production-environment

What could be wrong with my CSS when I lift Sails in production mode?

PS: I use Sails v0.10.5, bootstrap v3.2.0 and a custom css file for custom css stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: It was a probably a bad written css tag of mine. No idea why it is only a problem in production mode.

here the problematical tag:

```
.form-signin {
    width: 300px;
    padding: : 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: @lightGray;
    border: 1px solid @green;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Without the h2 definition it works as in development mode.